# How do I add a nested field to my BigQuery table schema?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to add a nested field to my BigQuery table schema. I can usually do this through the Web UI or command line, but when I try with a nested field I get the following error since the new field name had a `.` in it:

```
Error updating schema: Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.
```

How can I add a nested field?

Answer (score 8):

Using the `bq` command line tool, first export the table's schema:

```
bq show --format=prettyjson your-project:your_dataset.table_to_update | python -c 'import sys,json; print(json.dumps(json.load(sys.stdin)["schema"]["fields"]))' > table_schema.json
```

Then manually add your new nested field to the JSON. Once it's added, push the updated schema to BigQuery:

```
bq update -t --schema='updated_table_schema.json' your-project:your_dataset.table_to_update
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. It didn't work at first since it raises `No JSON object could be decoded`. But I edited the schema manually to get only the fields and it worked.

Comment: It is possible to add a nullable nested field automatically with `SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION` enabled when writing?